# By Mistakes i have deleted my store view in magento version 1.9.3.6

Tags: store-view, stores, magento-1.9.3.6

By Mistakes i have deleted my **store view** in **magento version 1.9.3.6**.

Can not able to see front end store view.

[image]

any help would be much appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: Contact your hosting support for recent database backup

Comment: @Pankaj Pareek .. unfortunety i have taken database back and just import it and made the connection after its works perfectly....hurrey..

Comment: @PankajPareek, i am not able to see the category and sub category  in magento version 1.9.3.6 version. need urgent help .

Comment: Hi Wasim have you still the problem?